# Outgoing calls are not go through on live server using Twilio JS client

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I have implemented Twilio JS client, everything is working good on localhost.
I can receive incoming calls and make outgoing calls to my verified number but when deployed to live, outgoing calls are not going through.

Initially I thought it is something related to SSL as Chrome was saying at console that it can't allow getUserMedia() without SSL. 
Now I got the SSL for server, Chrome's warning is gone and Chrome seems happy now.

After getting SSL when I try to make call, it starts to dial (earlier it wasn't dialing at all) but call ends with "An application error has occurred..."  voice message.

Is there any restriction that we can't make outgoing calls on live servers / domains while using demo accounts?

Comment: There aren't restrictions, but you may want to check [Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts) in your Twilio account to see what caused the errors. That should give you an idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: I agree with @philnash, looking at the logs in twilio will give you an idea of what is failing. Just make sure you have error reporting turned on, and it will display on the call log. Once you have the error if you still need help please post the error.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, checking logs will begin to point you in the right direction. If you are unsure of what a specific error means, you can refer to the Client error codes [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/errors).

And be sure that you enable debugging to receive verbose logs via the console.

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token, { debug: true }); // enable debug logging
```